# Not able to v-bind:style in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to change my text to red when there is a change to the textbox, but even though my value turned to true my text doesn't change color. I thought about using the conditional v-bind:style, but I'm not sure if I've done it wrong.

Here is my code

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="product in products">
                        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input  @change="onChange(product.price)"
                                    :style="[dirty ? 'color: red' : '']"
                                    v-model="product.price"
                            >
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        props: ['products],
        data() {
            return {
                dirty: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onChange(value)
            {
                return this.dirty = true;
            }
        },
        mounted(){

        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: 1. why do u have it in an array? Shouldn't it just be a string? 2. Move it to a method.

Comment: So I removed the array, but all my input boxes have turned red instead of the one I changed

Comment: You may need to make dirty into an array or object.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    products: [{
      name: 'one',
      price: 1
    }, {
      name: 'two',
      price: 2
    }],
    dirty: false,
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(product, i) in products" :key="i">
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <input @focus="dirty = product.name" :style="{color: dirty === product.name ? 'red' : 'black'}">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

use an object in your style binding and use a computed to return a value based on the condition.

for example in your template you can have:

```
<input :style="{ color: conditionalColor}">
```

then in your computed you have:

```
computed: {
  conditionalColor() {
    return this.dirty ? 'red' : '';
  }
}
```

and you can also read this part of the documentation for further info:

[style binding object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1)

**Edit**:
so because you are using a `v-for` and use a general variable i.e. `dirty` to toggle the style binding, when you change it all the input colors get changed, what you can do is to make the variable be specific to just one element (also it is a best practice to use `key` whenever you are using a `v-for` to avoid weird behavior from vue).

here is what I put together to give you an idea on how to do this, I used the `dirty` variable as a temporary value holder of the product name that its input is in focus right now and in the style binding check if this temporary variable match the `product.name` or not and by this I can toggle the focused input color between 'red' and 'black'.

also if you change `@focus` to `@input` you can see the color toggle effect only on the current input.

run the code and see for yourself (hope this helps)

Comment: I've done that, but all my input boxes have turned red instead of the one I changed

Comment: ow! my bad! sorry! didn't notice you used `v-for` that's why they all are turning red, let me see if I can edit the answer